# Placing a background image with text over it

Tags: images, html, custom-background

I'd like to place an image of a blueprint behind a section of text.

Things I'm worried about:

- Image will be tiled
- Image will stretch weird
- Image will look bad on different screen resolutions

What's the best way to incorporate a background image without it looking bad on different formats?

Here is a mockup of what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HtKM.jpg

Comment: Mind you us your work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how important the image is, can you do it with CSS.

CSS3 has an attribute called background-size:cover. This does not stretch the image,but it will scale it until it fits the whole area. Depending on the sizes some parts could be hidden.

[w3schools on background-size](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)